# Cannot run mysql after update to 20.04

Tags: apt, package-management, apache2, mysql

I've just upgraded from 19.10 to 20.04.
All went fine, but I have problem with mysql.
Here the currently installed packages:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep mysql
ii  libmysqlclient21:amd64                            8.0.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1                     amd64        MySQL database client library
ii  mysql-apt-config                                  0.8.15-1                                    all          Auto configuration for MySQL APT Repo.
ii  mysql-common                                      8.0.19-1ubuntu19.10                         amd64        Common files shared between packages
ii  php-mysql                                         2:7.4+75                                    all          MySQL module for PHP [default]
ii  php7.4-mysql                                      7.4.3-4ubuntu1.1                            amd64        MySQL module for PHP
```

I need to install `mysql-server` in order to use the `mysql` command. But:

> mysql-server depends mysql-server-8.0 but it is not going to be installed

trying to install `mysql-server-8.0`:

> mysql-server depends mysql-client-8.0 but it is not going to be installed

trying to install `mysql-client-8.0`:

> mysql-client-8.0 : depends mysql-common (>= 5.5)

But I have `mysql-common` at version 8.0.19 so the depencendy should be met!
I also tried to remove `mysql-common` in order to install it again but it would remove half of my system:

> colord gnome-control-center hplip libhpmud0 libmysqlclient21 libsane libsane-hpaio libsnmp35 mysql-common printer-driver-hpcups sane-utils ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-desktop-minimal

I also tried with:

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall mysql-server
```

How can I fix this situation?

### UPDATE

```
$ sudo apt install mysql-server-8.0
Lettura elenco dei pacchetti... Fatto
Generazione albero delle dipendenze       
Lettura informazioni sullo stato... Fatto
Alcuni pacchetti non possono essere installati. Questo può voler dire
che è stata richiesta una situazione impossibile oppure, se si sta
usando una distribuzione in sviluppo, che alcuni pacchetti richiesti
non sono ancora stati creati o sono stati rimossi da Incoming.
Le seguenti informazioni possono aiutare a risolvere la situazione:

I seguenti pacchetti hanno dipendenze non soddisfatte:
 mysql-server-8.0 : Pre-dipende: mysql-common (>= 5.5)
                    Dipende: mysql-client-8.0 (>= 8.0.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ma non sta per essere installato
                    Dipende: mysql-common (>= 5.8+1.0.4~)
E: Impossibile correggere i problemi, ci sono pacchetti danneggiati bloccati.
```

Comment: @user535733, done. I did not insert the complete message because it is in Italian language

Comment: Aha: "ci sono pacchetti danneggiati bloccati" ("*You have held broken packages*"). At some point, perhaps before upgrading to 20.04, you installed packages from some non-Ubuntu source. Those packages *conflict* with the current mysql packages. Whatever that source was, you must uninstall all packages from that source. Then installing mysql will work.

Comment: @user535733, it's very annoying. Currently I have only ubuntu sources in source.list. Perhaps in the past I installed something from other repositories as their own documentation suggested. But now it's hard to remember!

Comment: Why I cannot just uninstall `mysql` packages? I tried to uninstall some packages from third part sources (like Kicad or Teamviewer) but nothing has changed. How to find out all of them?

Comment: You can uninstall mysql packages if you want. It might help, it might not  If not, then keep going down the chain of erroring packages (`mysql-server` -> `mysql-server-8.0` -> `mysql-common` -> and so on...) until you get a different error message.

Comment: @user535733, ok thanks. But removing `mysql-common` will remove also `ubuntu-desktop`... does it mean I will not be able to use the desktop environment anymore?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inspecting the policy for the offending package I got:

```
$ apt policy mysql-common
mysql-common:
  Installato: 8.0.19-1ubuntu19.10
  Candidato:  8.0.19-1ubuntu19.10
  Tabella versione:
 *** 8.0.19-1ubuntu19.10 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     5.8+1.0.5ubuntu2 500
        500 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
```

Hence I guessed something went wrong during upgrade to 20.04.
I removed this package (along all the other related ones) with:

```
sudo apt remove mysql-common
```

Then the same command above returned:

```
$ apt policy mysql-common
mysql-common:
  Installato: (nessuno)
  Candidato:  5.8+1.0.5ubuntu2
  Tabella versione:
     8.0.19-1ubuntu19.10 -1
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     5.8+1.0.5ubuntu2 500
        500 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
```

Installing again the removed packages (now from the `focal` sources, instead of the 19.04) with:

```
sudo apt install mysql-server ubuntu-desktop-minimal
```

fixed the issue.

Comment: Glad to see you found the non-Ubuntu packages and removed them!

Comment: @user535733, that's the problem. I *did not* find any non-Ubuntu packages! I haven't removed anything but `mysql-common`. And as you can see it was from Ubuntu 19.10. I guess the upgrade process has failed.

Comment: The version of `mysql-common` in 19.10 is 5.8+1.0.5ubuntu2. I don't know where you got 8.0.19-1ubuntu19.10 from, but it wasn't from an Ubuntu source. Anybody can put the word 'ubuntu' into a version string; I always check the actual Ubuntu repositories using `apt cache madison package_name`.

Comment: Perfect thank you. Also doing upgrade from 18 to 20 and had same error. Was not able to google it, but when I was about to ask same question, SE editor pointed me to this. Please mark your answer as best solution.